# Formula in Sheets to break an IMPORTRANGE link after a certain date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm using the IMPORTRANGE formula to link cells from one Google Spreadsheet document to another Google Spreadsheet document. The links and updated cells are permanent. I'd like the updates on the links to expire after a certain date so the data remains fixed after that date. Does anyone know a formula for that? Thank you

Comment: for this you will need a script

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets